# jQuery fullCalendar - Refresh calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm working with [jQuery fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). This is the initialisation of my fullcalendar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#calendar').length) {
        var dbEvents = <?php echo $events; ?>;
        var calEvents = getEvents(dbEvents);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next',
            weekends: false,
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekNumberCalculation: "ISO",
            defaultView: 'month',
            defaultDate: moment(),
            height: 450,
            events: calEvents,
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                displayEvent(calEvent, calendar);
            }
        });
    }

});

/**
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function getEvents(dbEvents)
{
    calendarEvents = [];
    $.each( dbEvents, function( key, value ) {
        calendarEvents.push(createEvent(key, value));
    });

    return calendarEvents;
}

/**
 * @param eventStart
 * @param eventData
 * @returns {{start: *, allDay: boolean, backgroundColor: string, title: (string|*), textColor: string, data: *}|*}
 */
function createEvent(eventStart, eventData)
{
    if (eventData.full === true) {
        calendarEvent = {
            start: eventStart,
            allDay: true,
            backgroundColor: '#7B040B',
            title: 'Volzet',
            textColor: '#FFFFFF',
            data: eventData
        };

        return calendarEvent;
    }

    eventTitle = eventData.total_count + ' / ' + eventData.limit;
    calendarEvent = {
        start: eventStart,
        allDay: true,
        backgroundColor: '#076d09',
        title: eventTitle,
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        data: eventData
    };

    return calendarEvent;
}

function displayEvent(event, calendar)
{
    eventPopup = $("#popitup").bPopup({
        content:'iframe',
        loadUrl:'/application/packages/reservatie/event.php?date=' + event.data.date_id,
        onClose: function () {
            //@todo: update events

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
    });

    eventPopup.trigger('click');
}
```

As you can see in the function **displayEvent** I have the function on close of the popup where I try to refresh the events with **refetchEvents**.

The problem here is that I doesn't do anything... . The events aren't refreshed .. What could be the solution here?

Comment: seems like popup's `onClose` code is getting executed within `iframe` and not on the page where `fullCalendar` widget is present i.e. master page.

Comment: Quick and Dirty One -  Destroy calendar and rebuild calendar.. Check if your problem resolves or not.. also put the getEvents method within the calendar context. That is  events: getEvents. Mostprobably refetchEvents will work in this case

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. You code actually does nothing... What is the question?